# How to increase or decrease the time of the splash screen/launch screen of the react native ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, splash-screen

I am working with `react native`. In my project I used splash screen for both `Android` and `iOS`. On `Android` I increased the time of the splash screen in `android/app/src/main/java/splashActivity.java` as `sleep(5000)`. Similarly, I want to increase or decrease the time of the splash screen on `iOS`.
I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? How did you add sleep(5000) in Android?